How to get coverage reporting when testing an Ansible lookup plugin
I am developing an Ansible lookup plugin and test code for it. Both the lookup plugin and the test code for the plugin work fine.
I am using pytest with pytest-ansible for that test, and the test function uses the ansible_module fixture provided by pytest-ansible to invoke the builtin set_fact module to invoke the lookup. The test function looks like this (simplified):
import pytest
from pytest_ansible.fixtures import ansible_module

@pytest.mark.ansible(host_pattern='localhost', connection='local')
def test_mylookup(ansible_module):
    expr = "lookup('myorg.mycoll.mylookup', 'someterm')"
    contacted = ansible_module.set_fact(result=f"{{{{ {expr} }}}}")
    contacted_host = contacted['localhost']
    result = contacted_host['ansible_facts']['result']
    # assertions on result

Update: I found that importing ansible_module is not necessary for pytest to find the fixture.
The problem is that this test does not add to the test coverage (0%). Other Python modules in the project do add to the test coverage, just the tests for Ansible plugins do not.
I suppose this is because the ansible_module object at some point uses Ansible mechanisms to execute the module, and that probably lets my lookup code run in a different thread or process. But this is speculation.
I am using the pytest-cov and coverage packages to have pytest count the coverage, and run the test by invoking pytest with --cov* options.
Relevant Python package versions (on Python 3.9):
ansible                   8.7.0
ansible-core              2.15.13
pytest                    7.4.4
pytest-ansible            4.1.1
pytest-cov                6.0.0
coverage                  7.6.4

I would like to know how I can get the test coverage properly accounted for when testing an Ansible lookup plugin with pytest.

I also asked this question here: https://github.com/ansible/pytest-ansible/issues/411
